# How can I use Create with filtering in MVC 5 CRUD operation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, crud

I have a Customer table and Approval table as shown below. I created my Customer Controller and Views and its working. In `CustomerView.cshtml` the user cannot see the `CustActive` columns.

Now I need to create an `ApprovalController` with filtering. In `Approval.cshtml` page when I click on Create button I need to load the ComboBox that contains a Customer Name and Surname where `CustActive = False`. Then, when I select a customer from the ComboBox, I want to create columns such as `CustId`, `ManagerName` and `ManagerSurname` that will be activated for editing. After the edit I need to save the data for the Approval Table and insert true value for `CustActive` columns in Customer Table.

How can I do that?

**CUSTOMER TABLE**

```
CustId
Name
Surname
CustActive
```

---

**APPROVAL TABLE**

```
AppId
CustId
ManagerName
ManagerSurname
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you need insert in APPROVAL TABLE costumer properties yes?
Now after you created costumer you have define active as false and this is ok, after this you have write your APPROVAL controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "AppId,CustId,ManagerName,ManagerSurname")] Approval approval, string id)
{
var costumer = await db.Costumers.SingleAsync(x => x.CustId == id);
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    approval.CustId = id;
    CUSTOMER model = new CUSTOMER();
    model.CustActive = true;
    db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Categories.Add(category);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

return View(approval);
```

}